Size of an angle in rectangle
Problem: A rectangle ABCD is twice as wide as high. The rectangle EFGH is inscribed in ABCD so that E is the midpoint of AD and G is the midpoint of BC.
What is the size of angle DFE?
What I tried: I tried using similar triangles and got $\angle DFE$, by letting $\angle EFD=\theta$ and therefore $\angle GFC=90^o-\theta$, then WLOG letting the height of the rectangle be $2$. therefore $DC=4$, letting $FC=x$ and $DF=4-x$. Then using similar triangles on $\triangle FDE$ and $\triangle GCF$ I got that $tan\theta=\frac{1}{2+\sqrt3}$. We are trying to find theta, but how do you find it without a calculator?


Please include a picture/diagram of this.

Let $O$ be the midpoint of $EG$, and $X$ is the intersection of the perpendicular from $H$ to $EG$.
Then by Thales' Theorem, $|HO|=2$ and $|HX|=1$. Then, by Pythagoras' Theorem, $|XO|=\sqrt{3}$.
Therefore $\angle HOX=\cos^{-1}\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}=\frac{\pi}{6}$.
$EH$ is a chord on circle $O$, therefore by inscribed angles, $\angle HGE=\frac{\pi}{12}$.
